Data retrievel from firebase
I am unable to fetch and retrieve data from Firebase.
Data is like users node--> patient1--> aadharnumber--> aadharnumber or voter ID or driving license(these are my primary keys to access and retrieve the data). When ever I try to fetch or retrieve the primary keys are not matching  and i didnt get any errors
I am attaching the code here please feel free to reach out me if any modification can be done
package com.example.emergencyconnect;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class Hospital_personal_information extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText TextAadhaar, TextVoterId, TextDrivingLicense, TextVehicleNumber;
    private Button btnSearch;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hospital_personal_information);

        // Initialize Firebase Database reference
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

        // Initialize EditText fields and Button
        TextAadhaar = findViewById(R.id.TextAadhaar);
        TextVoterId = findViewById(R.id.TextVoterId);
        TextDrivingLicense = findViewById(R.id.TextDrivingLicense);
        TextVehicleNumber = findViewById(R.id.TextVehicleNumber);
        btnSearch = findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);

        // Set OnClickListener for the search button
        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                searchEmergencyContacts();
            }
        });
    }

    private void searchEmergencyContacts() {
        // Get input from EditText fields
        String aadhaar = TextAadhaar.getText().toString().trim();
        String voterId = TextVoterId.getText().toString().trim();
        String drivingLicense = TextDrivingLicense.getText().toString().trim();
        String vehicleNumber = TextVehicleNumber.getText().toString().trim();

        // Determine which query to use based on provided input
        Query query = null;
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(aadhaar)) {
            query = databaseReference.orderByChild("aadharnumber").equalTo(aadhaar);
        } else if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(voterId)) {
            query = databaseReference.orderByChild("voterid").equalTo(voterId);
        } else if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(drivingLicense)) {
            query = databaseReference.orderByChild("drivinglicense").equalTo(drivingLicense);
        } else if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(vehicleNumber)) {
            query = databaseReference.orderByChild("vehiclenumber").equalTo(vehicleNumber);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter at least one value to search",                                                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           return;
       }

       // Execute the query
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // Check if data exists for the provided input
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    // Get the first matching record
                    DataSnapshot record = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator().next();
                    String patientKey = record.getKey(); // Get the unique Firebase key

                    // Pass the key to the next activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Hospital_personal_information.this, Hospital_Patient_personal_details.class);
                    intent.putExtra("patient_key", patientKey); // Pass the key
                    startActivity(intent); // Start the second activity
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Hospital_personal_information.this, "No matching record found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(Hospital_personal_information.this, "Error: " + databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}

I am expecting that this should match my data and retrieve the data into next pages and display there
output expected
     {
      "users": {
        "4321": {
          "aadhaarNumber": "4321",
          "address": "fff",
          "age": "22",
          "bloodgroup": "212",
          "conditionName": "",
          "day": "06",
          "drivingLicense": "3",
          "fatherName": "313",
          "maritalStatus": "Single",
          "medicationName": "",
          "month": "January",
          "name": "313",
          "panNumber": "3",
          "vehicleNumber": "2",
          "voterId": "2",
          "year": "2002"
        },


"When ever I try to fetch or retrieve the primary keys are not matching" is not clear to me. Is there an error message? If not, can you log some output that isn't what you expect it to be? --- It'd also be good to see some of the data at databaseReference that you expect to be returned (as JSON text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your Firebase Database console.

Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

@AlexMamo I have made changes whatever frank asked me so can you please check now

Is your onDataChange triggered?

@AlexMamo yes it is triggered and gives result as no matching record found which is in else condition

Did you try to query the database using a hard-coded value? Are you getting the same result?

@AlexMamo I don't have much knowledge of querying in firebase is there any alternative solution like modifying the code
